# dotplot with two variables

Tags: r, variables, polymer

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(227, 222, 218, 216, 218, 217, 225, 229, 228, 221)
                 ,b=c(219, 214, 218, 203, 215, 211, 209, 204, 201, 205))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df,aes(a, b))+geom_dotplot()
```

I'd like to express a and b group with a different mark.

Comment: This could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33536095/in-ggplot-adding-legend-labels-to-manual-color-scale-causes-two-legends-to-appe

Answer (score 0):

We need to reshape to 'long' format

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
df %>%
     pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
     ggplot(aes(x =  value, color = name, fill = name)) +
      geom_dotplot()
```